# Codeigniter - Doubt with library and post

Tags: codeigniter, validation

I have created a library called `Fields` where I will create some custom fields.

I have a method `new()` that is checking for the post information and validating what is necessary.

The problem is, how will I send the post information to that library?

Or, should I make the validation on my controller and send the information as a parameter to the method `new()`?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array = $this->input->post()
```

will give you an array of your post data you can send as an argument to your library.

Answer (score 3):

In your controller, loading variables in an array and pass it to the library:

```
$params = array('type' => $this->input->post('large'), 
    'color' => $this->input->post('red'));
$this->load->library('Fields', $params);
//Usage...
$this->Fieds-method();
```

Like [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the post variable inside of your library, but I would validate the information in the controller before it's sent to the library.